# How to use django asynhronous programming with drf API views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-asyncio, asgi

I am trying to implement asynchronous programming with django rest framework and I am using `api_view` decorators for my function based API views. So I was trying to convert my synchronous method to asynchronous with `asgiref.sync.sync_to_async` decorator but seems like using this django is not able to route to my API view. Here is my function based api view.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes, api_view, authentication_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

from ..customauth import CustomAuthBackend
from ..utils.auth_utils import AuthUtils


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@authentication_classes([])
@sync_to_async
def login(request):
    email = request.data.get('email')
    if email is None or email == '':
        return Response(data={'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid credentials'})

    user = User.get_by_email(email=email)

    if user is not None and user.is_active and user.check_password(raw_password=request.data.get('password')):
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        tokens_map = AuthUtils.generate_token(request=request, user=user)
        return Response({'success': True, 'user': serializer.data, 'tokens': tokens_map})

    return Response(data={'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid login credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

If I use `async def` that is also not working with django rest framework. How do I make the use of event loop here efficiently ?

Answer (score 0):

Django has support for writing asynchronous `async` views, along with an entirely async-enabled request stack if you are running under ASGI.

You can try removing the `@sync_to_async` decorator, defining the view with the `async` keyword, and then wrapping every `sync` function you are using in your view with a `sync_to_async` wrapper

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes, api_view, authentication_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from ..customauth import CustomAuthBackend
from ..utils.auth_utils import AuthUtils

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@authentication_classes([])
async def login(request):
    email = request.data.get('email')
    if email is None or email == '':
        return Response(data={'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid credentials'})

    user = await sync_to_async(User.get_by_email)(email=email)

    if user is not None and user.is_active and user.check_password(raw_password=request.data.get('password')):
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        tokens_map = await sync_to_async(AuthUtils.generate_token)(request=request, user=user)
        return Response({'success': True, 'user': serializer.data, 'tokens': tokens_map})

    return Response(data={'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid login credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

---

Another approach would be using a third party like `celery`, you can install it using this command:

> pip install celery[redis]

then inside your `settings.py` add the following:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

and update your view according to the changes you would make to the rest of the code to accommodate `celery`.

celery docs: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/index.html

---

If you are hosting this code make sure that you are using an `ASGI` server like `Daphne`, as synchronous servers like the default `WSGI` server won't be able to handle asynchronous views properly also make sure that you add your routes to the `asgi.py` file if needed, it is a must if you are using something like Django channels but apply this your specific case.

Comment: so even if I use asyncio.run(async_method) within my view it will block the asgi event loop, right? @Ahmad

Comment: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'coroutine'>`. I am getting this error with your first approach